# Log values by SFrame column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, logarithm

Please, can anybody tell me, how I can take logarithm from every value in [SFrame](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.html), graphlab (or [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), pandas) column, without to iterate through the whole length of the SFrame column? 
I specially interest on similar functionality, like by [Groupby Aggregators](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/graphlab.data_structures.html) for the log-function. Couldn't find it someself...

**Important:** Please, I don't interest for the `for-loop` iteration for the whole length of the column. I only interest for specific function, which transform *all* values to the log-values for the whole column.

I'm also very sorry, if this function is in the manual. Please, just give me a link...

Comment: What about `numpy.log`? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html

Comment: ok, numpy will probably also go. Anyway, if somebody know specific function from pandas or graphlab package, please let me also know. @cel, Anyway - yes, I accept your answer too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`numpy` provides implementations for a wide number of basic mathematical transformations. You can use those on all data structures that build on numpy's `ndarray`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.Series([np.exp(1), np.exp(2), np.exp(3)])
np.log(data)
```

Outputs:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: float64
```

This example is for `pandas` data types, but it works for all data structures that are based on `numpy` arrays.

Answer (score 5):

The same "apply" pattern works for SFrames as well. You could do:

```
import graphlab
import math

sf = graphlab.SFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
sf['b'] = sf['a'].apply(lambda x: math.log(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

**@cel**

I think, in my case it could be possible also to use next pattern.

```
import numpy
import pandas
import graphlab


df
    a b c 
    1 1 1 
    1 2 3
    2 1 3
    ....

df['log c'] = df.groupby('a')['c'].apply(lambda x: numpy.log(x))
```

for SFrame (`sf` instead `df` object) it could look little be different

```
logvals = numpy.log(sf['c'])
log_sf = graphlab.SFrame(logvals)
sf = sf.join(log_sf, how = 'outer')
```

Probably with `numpy` the code fragment is a little bit to long, but it works...

The main problem is of course time perfomance. I did hope, I can fnd some specific function to minimise my time....

Comment: The groupby you do (`df.groupby('a')['c'].apply(lambda x: numpy.log(x))`) seems superfluous. You are not doing anything different to the different groups, so this will just be equivalent to `df['log c'] = np.log(df['c'])` (the answer of @cel). And I don't think you will find something faster with pandas.